# Different hierarchical clustering results

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I'm running a hierarchical clustering on a sample of data using the steps below:

```
library(RODBC)

setwd('D:/r/cluster2')
channel <- odbcConnectExcel('cluster.xls')
data <- sqlFetch(channel, 'clust9')

y9 <- data.frame(inf=data$infest, faible=data$faible, moyen=data$moyen, fort=data$fort, lon=data$Lon, lat=data$Lat)

y9 <- na.omit(y9) # listwise deletion of missing
y9.use <- y9
y9 <- scale(y9) # standardize variables

wss <- (nrow(y9)-1)*sum(apply(y9,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(y9, centers=i)$withinss)

plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares")

# K-Means Cluster Analysis
fit <- kmeans(y9, 5) # 5 cluster solution

aggregate(y9,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)

y9 <- data.frame(y9, fit$cluster)

# Ward Hierarchical Clustering

d <- dist(y9, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix

fit <- hclust(d, method="ward") 

plot(fit) # display dendogram

rect.hclust(fit, k=5, border="red")
```

and i got this results:

[image]

But when I did the same steps the next day I got different results: 
[image]

They are not different in everything, but there are individual that they now belong to another cluster!

so I don't know why  this behavior? i'm interested in interpreting and explaning the results, so when i get different results each time, that will make my previous interpretation wrong, what can I do for now ?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `kmeans` function, which will not give the same exact results every time you run it.

The [k-means algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) works by using randomly chosen centroids as a starting point. These are generated using R [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRNG) (PRNG).

The PRNG generates a series of random values which depend on a seed.
From `?set.seed`:

> Initially, there is no seed; a new one is created from the current time (and since R 2.14.0, the process ID) when one is required. Hence different sessions will give different simulation results, by default. However, the seed might be restored from a previous session if a previously saved workspace is restored.

If you want to always obtain the same results you should impose a seed at the start of your script.

For instance:

```
set.seed(12345)
```

Different seeds will give different results, but once you have fixed it it will always be the same.

Now, the fact that:

> They are not different in everything, but there are individual that they now belong to another cluster!

Is a good thing, it means that you can cluster most individuals with good confidence. Probably the ones that change between clusters are a bit "borderline".

One thing that you should do, however, is to set the `nstart` parameter in `kmeans`. Setting `nstart` to 10, for instance, will make the algorithm run 10 times, with 10 different starting sets of points and return the best fit (the one with the minimum within cluster sums-of-squares).

This will help in reducing "bad clustering" due to an "unlucky" choice of starting points.

Finally, I am not completely sure what is the point of running `hclust` on the `kmeans` results. Either run `hclust` directly on the original data, or just show the `kmeans` results.

Comment: Although k-means is also based on pseudorandom number generator, the problem here arises from the fact that `hclust` function is also based on the PRNG and thus `set.seed()` is also needed before generating any `hclust` result to ensure reproducibility.